# Usar método .POST ou .DELETE para requisição de excluir dados

Tags: java, spring-mvc

Estava usando .delete mas de uma hora para a outra o método não esta sendo reconhecido da o erro no console.

> 2017-04-12 09:51:34.022  WARN 5836 --- [nio-8080-exec-9] o.s.web.servlet.PageNotFound             : Request method 'POST' not supported

Estou mandando assim no html.

```
  <form method="post">
        <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="DELETE"/> </form>
```

e meu controller esta assim.

```
@PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('PERM_MANTENEDORA_EXCLUIR')")
@RequestMapping(value = "/excluir/{id}", method = RequestMethod.DELETE)*****************
public String excluirMantenedora(@PathVariable("id") Mantenedora mantenedora, RedirectAttributes attributes) {

    if (mantenedora.getSituacao().getNome() == "ativo") {
        try {
            // condição para não deixar EXCLUIR quando tiver algum vínculo.
            List<Instituicao> instituicoes = instituicaoRepository.findByMantenedoraId(mantenedora.getId());
            if (instituicoes.size() <= 0) {
                mantenedoraService.excluir(mantenedora.getId());
                mensagem = mensagemSucesso(MensagemEnum.MENSAGEM_SUCESSO_EXCLUIR.getMensagem());
            } else {
                mensagem = mensagemErro(MensagemEnum.MENSAGEM_ERRO_VINCULO.getMensagem());
            }
        } catch (CustomException e) {
            mensagem = mensagemErro(e.getMessage());
        }

        attributes.addFlashAttribute("mensagem", mensagem);
    }
    return "redirect:/mantenedora";
}
```

Se eu trocar o DELETE para POST funciona mas quero saber porque aconteceu isso do método DELETE não ser reconhecido.

Comment: vc precisa mudar em seu form o method de `<form method="post">` para `<form method="delete">`. Isto ocorre pq seu método espera um chamada via Delete, `RequestMethod.DELETE` mas dentro de seu form vc está passando a chamada via post `<form method="post">`

Comment: vlw pela dica mas eu tentei e agora deu erro no Get.

Comment: 2017-04-12 10:34:40.317  WARN 3788 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.s.web.servlet.PageNotFound             : Request method 'GET' not supported

Comment: `GET`, `POST`, `PUT` e `DELETE` (há outros) são uma parte do padrão `HTTP`, mas pelo que vi, formulários `HTML` são limitados a `GET` e `POST`. Uma solução seria realmente utilizar como `POST` ou ainda usar `PUT` e `DELETE` com solicitações `AJAX`. Para isto, consutle http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/